# Xamarin iOS 11 Thread UI Culture wrong

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, ios11

With the iOS 11 update, the wrong culture is set in the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. The app is not translated and the date format is incorrect. The iPad is set to de-DE (German) and the thread has en-Us culture. NSLocaleCurrentLocale.LanguageCode is en. However, the setting in NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CollatorIdentifier is de-DE. Does anyone have this issue? Is there a solution for already installed apps?

Comment: The issue can be fixed temporarily by deleting all other language packs from the iPad, See [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103897/ios-11-bug-thread-currentuiculture#latest)

Comment: I found the bug is reported at Xamarin. Take a look [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59596)